# Azure VPN as a VPN Server and a Proxy Server

Tags: azure-vpn

I would like to ask if the Azure VPN can be used to both act as a VPN tunnel and a Proxy Server.

We have subscribed for Azure VPN and is located in Singapore to resolve latency issues in connecting to one of our client in the US, which is hosting their VDI in the US. This has been resolved using the said solution. The tunnel configuration has been setup by our MSP.

Now, we are also using OpenVPN that acts as Proxy Server to access another client's resources in the US. We are located in the Philippines and the client's network requires US IP address for their security. We are planning to refrain from using OpenVPN and utilize our new Azure VPN. The question is, will it be possible to create another tunnel in Azure VPN and use it as a proxy?

I am just starting my studies in Azure cloud technologies and I am not in-depth with their solutions. Thank you so much!

Creating another tunnel in Azure VPN to be used as a Proxy Server.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a bastion host in one of the US regions and use that to hop over to the cients network